# Limit database usage of a website

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, iis

To start off - I have 2 separate websites and a database (IIS 7.5, ASP.NET and SQL Server 2008, using Linq-To-SQL for database access).

I have a separate administrative website that sometimes, during usage needs to trigger long running operations (more than 10 seconds) on database. The problem is that those operations cause sqlserver process to hit 100% CPU and then other, main customer website, can't access database promptly - there are some delays in accessing database.

I am OK with those administrative operations lasting 2x or 4x or nx times longer since they are lower priority.

I've tried using CPU Limit setting on AppPool in IIS, but that doesn't help, as w3wp.exe process never uses much of CPU... rather it's sqlservr.exe. Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Just one thing - please do not respond with: optimize sql for those long running operations or point administrative website to separate database / server and then sync. I've tried to do that already. I am rather trying to find a way to say: "run this query but use max 30% of CPU" since it would be the best fix for my problem in terms of robustness. Or, if it is possible to set max CPU usage in connection string - that would be perfect.

Comment: What makes you think that limiting IIS resources would have any effect on the database?

Comment: @Oded I've mentioned that to prevent "Have tried limiting AppPool usage in IIS" answers... but, obviously, I've forgot that it may spark useless questions in comments. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to look into Resource Governor which is built into SQL server as of SQL 2008. BOL link should get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866(v=SQL.100).aspx

Essentially, you can throttle CPU and memory usage for the resource pools and workloads you define.  This throttling will only kick in when the server is under load.  Be aware that you cannot control disk IO utilization.  If the process in your admin database is IO bound and your other DBs share drives you will inevitably still see performance issues and moving databases to separate spindles or query tuning will be necessary.

Example of the classifier function that will ensure the user you define is throttled by the desired resource pool based on workload group:

```
/* Classifier function */
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.rgov_classifier_db ()
RETURNS sysname
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @rgWorkloadGrp sysname
    IF SUSER_SNAME() = 'adminWebsiteDB'
        SET @rgWorkloadGrp = 'workloadGroupName'
    ELSE
        SET @rgWorkloadGrp = 'defaultWorkloadGroupName'
    RETURN @rgWorkloadGrp
END;
GO
/* Register the function with Resource Governor and then start Resource Governor. */
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR
    WITH (CLASSIFIER_FUNCTION = dbo.rgov_classifier_db);
GO
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the link... I've already done some research into it and I would love if someone with more experience could tell me how to assign certain db user to certain Resource Pool. That is where I'm stuck right now...

Comment: Also, do you know if using Resource Governor can negatively influence performance of the database/application?

Comment: I do not have a lot of hands on experience, but what you are looking for is referred to as a "classifier function".  Nothing more than a normal UDF from the looks of things, but I believe it needs to be created in the [master] db.

Comment: You create a classifier function, which returns a resource pool. You can identify the user by login name (e.g. SUSER_SNAME()) and return your limited pool in that case, otherwise return the default. However the way Resource Governor works you won't see the throttling until there is contention. I wrote a whitepaper with Boris Baryshnikov, the lead architect of RG, and it includes several classifier function examples : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee151608(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If your admin queries are consuming all the CPU on the box, there is almost certainly some tuning opportunities there - likely some indexing optimizations.

In lieu of the time to invest in those, and until you get your Resource Governor configuration settled, you can simply reduce their impact to a single CPU, which may provide short-term symptom relief, by adding the MAXDOP hint to your admin query:

```
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

Yes, it might make you feel a little dirty, but the rest of your CPUs will be freed up to work on your more important queries.

The real answer is to tune your admin queries. Just because it's ok that they run long does not mean it's good for your server or the experience of your users. You'll never be able to completely isolate them from the effects of other queries going on on the box, especially if you are experiencing high CPU that is compensating for slow I/O. I/O does not have any knobs in resource governor - you can only control CPU and memory, and not even 100%.

Comment: Thanks for your response Aaron. I've managed to set that classifier function and assign my SQL user to proper group... but I still see 100% of CPU utilization. From what I read, I understand that Resource Governor will not kick in, unless there is competing for resources... but I don't need that - I need to limit the user to 50% of CPU usage all the time. Would setting Workload Group "Degree of Parallelism" to 1 (instead of 0) help?

Comment: 2 works perfect for 4 core machine I have... ;) Problem solved!

Comment: Why do you need to limit CPU to 50% even when nobody else is using the box? That should be a goal of tuning the query (no query should ever take 100% of the box) but why leave half the machine idle when nobody else needs it? Resource Governor *will* kick in when a second user gets on and tries to do something.

Comment: Well, that's not what I am getting on my machine. I have third process (that I haven't mentioned in question for sake of keeping question simple) that queries database every 500 milliseconds (and uses like 1% CPU). When I set Degree of Parallelism to 0, and execute long running task... database respond time for that third process jumps from 5 milliseconds to 300 milliseconds. Now, that is not big difference in absolute terms, but for my application IT IS HUGE. I guess Resource Governor doesn't have enough time to kick in properly, in this case.

Comment: You need to give Resource Governor a chance to respond. If you read the whitepaper you will see there are limitations to how quickly it will respond, and they are different for CPU requests (rather quick, but not immediate - this happens on a schedule, not in reaction to specific events) and memory requests (only enforced at next memory grant request). Have you validated that the 3rd process is waiting on CPU and that is the sole cause of the duration spike? Anyway I still think you're barking up the wrong tree here and should focus on optimizing the expensive query.

Comment: Heh ;) I'll gladly discuss this with you - always love to learn new approaches. But in this case, believe me, I'm stuck with what I have now. I've completely verified that 3rd process is waiting on Database access specifically... and the problem is that I can't optimize some of the queries fired from that admin website. For example - our management wants to be able to filter by ALL columns... and you can imagine what happens when they issue call that translates into Col1 LIKE '%john%' OR Col2 LIKE '%john%' OR Col3 LIKE '%john%'...

Comment: And... if you are only battling my solution for sake of future generations - sure, you are right - the solution I resorted to is far away from perfect. So - kids - do not do what I did... if you end up in same situation as I did - create mirror copy of database and point admin site to it for SELECT operations (of course keep INSERT/UPDATE operations on main database).